# AD8421 output AC or DC?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

Is the output of the [AD8421](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8421.pdf) AC or DC?

Comment: Its both kinds - your circuit determines this. What do you want to do with this chip?

Comment: You'd be better off describing what you're trying to achieve with the chip, and asking whether the chip can do it.  The chip needs DC power, but the output frequencies will depend on the nature of the input and how much gain you need.

Comment: Where do you  think you'll get a bare die chip?

Comment: The chip is an instrumentation amplifier. I could design a circuit using this chip where it will output **a DC voltage only**. I could also design a circuit where it will output **an AC voltage only**. I could also design a circuit where it outputs a voltage which is both **DC and AC at the same time**. The IC on its own cannot do much. You will have to use it **in a circuit** to do anything (useful) at all.

Comment: Same as you put in.

Answer (score 1):

The chip needs DC power, but the output frequencies will depend on the nature of the input and how much gain you need.  If you're using very high gain, you should expect to see dc offsets on any output.

You'd be better off describing what you're trying to achieve with the chip, and asking whether the chip can do it.

Comment: The AD8421 being a completely analog IC, I would say that restricting it to DC power robs it of some niche use cases..

Comment: @tobalt -- I'd love to hear about some of them. I can't imagine any where you'd power it with anything else, especially as most of the absolute maximum voltage specs are in terms of Vs

Comment: Nevermind. You are correct, I was just deterred by the rather absolute nature of the sentence about DC power. I just believe that there are circuits where modulating power is useful for something, but indeed probably not for ICs such as this. (If you read the absolute maximum ratings of the AD8421 carefully, you will realize that its inputs are actually rugged against power down.)

Comment: @tobalt -- I actually did review the absolute maximums, and they are impressive -- other than the voltage at Vref, which made me shiver a little bit about applying an AC signal to power.